# Matrix report formula on row sub grand total

Tags: reporting, formula, administration, system-admin, matrix

I have build the following matrix report, which is grouped in columns by a bucket field of my stages and by current and previous month for the closed date. This report is also grouped in rows by a look up field called ref accounts.

The goal of this report is to inform for each ref account, at each month what was their stats in a percentage.

For instance the first row referred a total of 84 in june (48 + 18 + 12 + 6) and so far 59 in july ( 25 + 17 + 15 + 1 + 1)

Right now my formula is getting the current cell value and divided by the whole row count 143 (june and july) but what it need to happen is that the cell should be divided by the month total, not both month combined, so the percentage of 48 should be done on 84 and not 143, making the total 57.14% and not 33.57%

[image]

this is the current formula i am using

```
RowCount /PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, Opportunity.Referrer_Account__c, COLUMN_GRAND_SUMMARY)
```

[image]

Comment: you could create a monthwise  summary field and then use that in the formula instead of COLUMN_GRAND_SUMMARY

Comment: Thank you for the info, could you please elaborate more?